# Query operations by id on ROLLING History Mode Node

Tags: node, rpc, operation

Is it possible to query operations by id using node synced in ROLLING History Mode?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The *rolling mode* was designed as a light mode which aims to "follow the chain" without keeping all its data. To do so, this mode keeps a few blocks from the current head and discards older data.

It is possible to query all the information regarding blocks which are included in the rolling windows, corresponding to the current cycle.

You can use the `tezos-client rpc get /chains/main/checkpoint` to show, among other things, the oldest block that contains all the data.

A comprehensive description of the history modes can be found in the documentation: http://tezos.gitlab.io/mainnet/user/history_modes.html